# HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated is false in Ajax request + OpenID Connect Cookie based validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We are using OpenIdConnect based authentication in the asp.net mvc application. Initial login is working fine. But when we use the Ajax call to invoke the action method, User is coming as not authenticated. I checked in Custom Authorization - `HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` is coming as false.

I checked the cookie  `".AspNet.Cookies"` and it has the value. Why is open ID not authenticating the user.

Below is my authentication code

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = AuthenticationConfig.ClientId,
                Authority = AuthenticationConfig.AADInstance + AuthenticationConfig.TenantId,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = AuthenticationConfig.PostLogoutRedirectURI,
                RedirectUri = AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                SaveTokens = true,

                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AuthenticationConfig.ClientSecret)),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = AuthenticationConfig.AADInstance + AuthenticationConfig.TenantId + "/v2.0",
                },

                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // when an auth code is received...
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
       {
           var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);

           //var claimsIdentity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
           var user = nid.Claims.Where(r => r.Type == PreferedUserNameClaimType).Select(v => v.Value).FirstOrDefault();

           var userRolesroles = GetRolesForUser(user);

           //nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

           userRolesroles.ToList().ForEach(ui => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, ui)));

           // keep the id_token for logout
           nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

           // add access token for sample API
           nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

           n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
              nid,
              n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

           UserService.SetUserInformation(user);

       },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
                    {
                        bool isAjaxRequest = (ctx.Request.Headers != null && ctx.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");

                        if (ctx.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                        {
                            if (isAjaxRequest && ctx.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                            {
                                ctx.Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
                                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                                ctx.HandleResponse();
                                return Task.FromResult(0);
                            }
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);

                    }
                }

            });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in asp.net, the ApiControllers has no concept of your Controller's authentication. Depending on the way things are builr, you need to add an Authorization header with a bearer access token to let the API know about the authenticated user.

Comment: It is not an APIController and is a MVC Controller.  Still I need to implement bearer token authentication?